# Error: Cannot find control with path: 'skills -> proficiency'

Tags: angular

I have an error in angular 8.I dont know where i my mistake.I specified the form group name.form array name ands its own form control name.It gives an error by the first radio button in the form group.

```
 <form [formGroup]="radioButtonsForm">
        <div formArrayName="skills">
          <label>Enter the proficiency level for {{pl}}</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="beginner" formControlName="proficiency">Beginner
          </label>

          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="intermediate" formControlName="proficiency">Intermediate
          </label>

          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="advanced" formControlName="proficiency">Advanced
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>



 ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.service.getAllProgrammingLanguages()
    .subscribe(x => {
      this.allPl = x;

      this.radioButtonsForm = this.fb.group({
        skills: this.fb.array([
        ])
      });
    })

}


 selectedPl(event)
  {
    this.lastValue = event;
    this.hasChoosed = true;
    this.choosedProgrammingLanguages = event;
    (<FormArray>this.radioButtonsForm.get('skills')).push(this.addSkillFormGroup());
  }
```

Comment: build your form first, then update your form after calling API

Comment: i tried that way too.The error still appears